# Cloudflare captchas when using Tor (but not with Tor Browser)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, cloudflare

So if i use Tor as proxies, i got Cloudflare chalenge captcha

```
proxies = {'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050',
           'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'}
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies = proxies
r = s.get(url)
print(r.headers)
```

if i do same reuest without proxies

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url)
print(r.headers)
```

I got response without Cloud protection, also same url is not blocking in Tor browser never on changing IPs.

What is proble can be with proxies? How to fix?

Comment: Cloudflare forces Tor users to complete frequent captchas, unless they use the Tor Browser specifically.

Comment: No captchas in Tor Browser, only if requests doing from script

Comment: Right, Cloudflare only shows captchas if you're not using the Tor Browser. They do this by fingerprinting the browser.

Comment: So, how to show with script what im using browser?

Comment: I don't know what fingerprinting mechanism Cloudflare uses and it isn't documented anywhere, so you'd need to figure that out.

Comment: But why cloudflare do not fingerprint browser without using proxies? and everythings work good

Comment: They do this to prevent people from writing bots and scraping their website over Tor.